# Flutter app crashes on firebase phone auth in iOS platform

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have implemented Firebase Phone auth in my project,

On android side everything works fine, but for iOS side, when i try to send verification code from my end, app crashes and lost connection.

I have submitted my code below.

**main.dart**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        home: new MyHomePage(),
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
          '/homepage': (BuildContext context) => MyApp(),
          '/landingpage': (BuildContext context) => MyHomePage()
        }
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String phoneNo;
  String smsCode;
  String verificationId;

  Future<void> verifyPhone() async {
    print("main");
    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrieve = (String verId) {
      print("varification id");
      this.verificationId = verId;
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent = (String verId, [int forceCodeResend]) {
      print("send code dilog");
      this.verificationId = verId;
      smsCodeDialog(context).then((value) {
        print('Signed in');
      });
    };

    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verifiedSuccess = (AuthCredential user){
      print('Phone Verification Completed');
    };

    final PhoneVerificationFailed veriFailed = (AuthException exception) {
      print('${exception.message}');
    };

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(

        phoneNumber: "+919700000000",
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieve,
        codeSent: smsCodeSent,
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        verificationCompleted: verifiedSuccess,
        verificationFailed: veriFailed);
  }

  Future<bool> smsCodeDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return new AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Enter sms Code'),
            content: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                this.smsCode = value;
              },
            ),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                child: Text('Done'),
                onPressed: () {
                  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
                    if (user != null) {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
                    } else {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      signIn();
                    }
                  });
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  signIn(){
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verificationId,
        smsCode: smsCode);

    FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential).then((user){
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
    }).catchError((e){
      print('Auth Credential Error : $e');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('PhoneAuth'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Phone number'),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    this.phoneNo = value;
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: verifyPhone,
                    child: Text('Verify'),
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    elevation: 7.0,
                    color: Colors.blue)
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is error while submit the button

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Dhruvin’s iPhone in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: ******
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           99.4s
Installing and launching...
Syncing files to device Dhruvin’s iPhone...
Lost connection to device.
```

However i am not able to see stacktrace or log as app lost connection from debugger.

Comment: If seems like there is some iOS configuration issue in app, please refer iOS setup part and follow all the steps (You need to add reverse client id as well please check conform you have implemented it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i Solved the Problem,
thank you so much @DevarshRanpura for Helping me,

1) replace

```
signIn(){
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verificationId,
        smsCode: smsCode);

    FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential).then((user){
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
    }).catchError((e){
      print('Auth Credential Error : $e');
    });
  }
```

to this

```
signIn() async {
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: verificationId,
      smsCode: smsCode,
    );
    final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;
    print('User Id : ' + user.uid);
  }
```

also Define _auth on your dart file

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

2) adding reverse client id in to your project

- open your project in xcode
- double click on your project name
- go to the info tab
- In URL Types->URL schemes add the reverse client Id

Comment: "In URL Types->URL schemes add the reverse client Id" -> can you explain this, please?

Comment: Here is a good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61514076/firebase-phone-auth-getting-ios-error-register-custom-url-scheme

Comment: thank you @ValentinSeehausen for more visual explaning the problem, now more devlopers can easy to solve this issue.