# Firestore phone verification causes ios to crash (Flutter)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add phone verification to my flutter app. It seems to work ok on android but on ios phone verification causes app to crash instantly. I am using the following in my pubspec.yaml:

```
firebase_auth: 0.15.4

dependency_overrides:
  firebase_core: 0.4.4
```

The output of flutter doctor is:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at /Users/gollyzoom/development/flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (3 months ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/gollyzoom/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3, Build version 11C29
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 39.0.3
    • Dart plugin version 191.8423
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1.4)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 38.1.3
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554                        • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max         • B3536B50-C435-4442-9CF4-69D470B979CA • ios         •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

The actual code i'm using is:

```
Future<void> verifyPhone() async {
    print("main");
    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrieve = (String verId) {
      print("varification id");
      this.verificationId = verId;
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent = (String verId, [int forceCodeResend]) {
      print("send code dilog");
      this.verificationId = verId;
      smsCodeDialog(context).then((value) {
        print('Signed in');
      });
    };

    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verifiedSuccess = (AuthCredential user){
      print('Phone Verification Completed');
    };

    final PhoneVerificationFailed veriFailed = (AuthException exception) {
      print('${exception.message}');
    };

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(

        phoneNumber: "+6505551234",
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieve,
        codeSent: smsCodeSent,
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        verificationCompleted: verifiedSuccess,
        verificationFailed: veriFailed);
  }

  Future<bool> smsCodeDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return new AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Enter sms Code'),
            content: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                this.smsCode = value;
              },
            ),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                child: Text('Done'),
                onPressed: () {
                  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
                    if (user != null) {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
                    } else {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      signIn();
                    }
                  });
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  signIn() async {
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: verificationId,
      smsCode: smsCode,
    );
    final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;
    print('User Id : ' + user.uid);
  }
```

I got this code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60374940/flutter-app-crashes-on-firebase-phone-auth-in-ios-platform) stack overflow post,  but I didn't know what they meant by "adding reverse client id in to your project". (i.e.  what is reverse client id, how do I add it), and their code didn't stop the app from crashing for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the "reverse client id" is in the GoogleService-info.plist. This is what you have to add in Xcode. Adding this resolved the crash.